# UPS is not working for heavy weight products

Tags: shipping-methods, ups, ce-1.9.1.1

I have Magento ver. 1.9.1.1. I have used the default UPS shipping method and my setting for it as listed below.

- Enabled for Checkout = yes
- UPS Type = united parcel service
- Gateway URL = http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi
- Packages Request Type = divide to equal rate
- Container = customer packaging
- Destination Type = residential
- Weight Unit = LBS
- Pickup Method = customer counter
- Maximum Package Weight  = 5000
- Minimum Package Weight  = 0.1
- Calculate Handling Fee = fixed
- Handling Applied = per package
- Handling Fee = 0
- Allowed Methods = all option selected
- Free Method = none
- Free Shipping with Minimum Order Amount = disabled
- Ship to Applicable Countries = all allowed countries
- Debug = no
- Show Method if Not Applicable = no

Now I have two products **A** (weight : 150.0000) and **B** (weight : 111.0000)

When I add **A** to shipping cart and check "Estimate Shipping and Tax" for united states - delaware - 19702. It shows me as expected options for UPS. But when I add **B** after **A** and try "Estimate Shipping and Tax", it does not show any shipping method. When i check log it gives me:

> UPSOnLine5%The maximum per package weight for the selected service
>   from the selected country is 150.00 pounds.%1035%

but my product have the larger weights.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a lot of time and testing I have the solution which ultimately Magento OOTB provides, Its just a matter for how to use it.

We can ship Bundle items separately. While creating bundle products use the following option.

[image: Bundle product setting]

Along with this, we have one more setting which is based on Clients’s business logic.

[image: Configuration setting]

The Maximum package weight will always be 150 due to UPS limitation. “Packages Request Type” has two options

- Divide to equal weight (one request): If total cart weight is for eg. 180lb, ups will calculate the rate for 180/2=90lb and if for eg. for 90lb UPS says it will cost $100, the final cost will be $100*2 = 200. i.e. two packages of 90lbs each.
- Use origin weight (few requests): If cart weight is 180lbs with one child product of 50lb and other of 130lbs, UPS will calculate the separate rate for 130lbs and 50lbs package by sending two requests to API and sum them up. For eg. of 130lbs package costs $100 and 50lbs package cost $60 the final shipping cost will be $100+$60=$160.
  Let me know which is suitable in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum package weight for UPS is 150 LBS.

You broke it with **Maximum Package Weight = 5000**

I'd like to see a UPS delivery car being loaded with a forklift...

Set it back to 150 LBS and make sure your per item weights don't exceed 150 LBS if you want to ship via UPS.

Note that UPS LTS is a different service and needs a different module. They actually send out a freight truck that can be loaded with a forklift.

Comment: Thanks Flasco Labs. But there are many products in my site that contain more than 150 lbs weight. So is there any solution for it or any other shipping method is available for it? pls help me.

Comment: How are you managing to ship stuff that has a package weight over 150 lbs? There is a weight limit on the package that the driver will accept? Or are you using UPS LTS which is partial trailer shipment? The UPS shipping calculator WILL NOT accept a package weight (item weight) over 150 LBS.

Comment: @FiascoLabs My store in India, so my default weight KGS. UPS for USA shipping, what i need to do with "Weight Unit"   KGS or LBS?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your setting  Maximum Package Weight = 5000

> The maximum per package weight is 150.00 pounds

Try by changing

> Container

to Large Express Box or Customer Supplied Package