# Magento 2 - Freight options for UPS possible?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shipping-methods

Magento 2.2.4

---

Running a B2B store on M2 CE 2.2.4, we tend to have some larger orders in both price and weight. Looking through the default shipping method options, FedEx gives a minimal amount of freight options in

```
3 Day Freight
2 Day Freight
1 Day Freight
```

Which I suppose could be better but atleast gives options, it doesn't appear UPS allows for any such options, so if the product weight for the order goes over the set amount (mind you, I've tried raising that to absurd amounts like 10,000 lbs and it still won't give any type of quote, so I assume the UPS API has it's own weight restrictions), it won't supply any quote at all and just throws the default error message of `This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.`.

Are there UPS Freight options available for Magento 2?

Comment: Please check Magento marketplace now many ups freight shipping plug-in available with one time cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of research and reaching out to UPS, it turns out they have Freight API's and other sources, but Magento natively only grabs their standard shipping API which does not include freight ground or LTL shipments.

That said, probably the best solution, though paid, appears to be shipperhq.com, which I will most likely be turning towards. Plenty of options and great support if anyone runs into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Better to contact UPS and ask for the specific weight restrictions within your region.

As for the default **Maximum Package Weight** it will always be **150** for **lbs** as to UPS limitation.

You can also specify from the **Allowed methods** the **Ground Commercial** method which is applicable to **Destination Type** of **Commercial**.

**[UPS Packages Request Type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86131/ups-is-not-working-for-heavy-weight-products?answertab=votes#tab-top)** has two options:

- Divide to equal weight (one request): If total cart weight is for eg. **180lb,** ups will calculate the rate for 180/2=90lb and if for eg. for **90lb** UPS says it will cost $100, the final cost will be **$100*2 = 200.** i.e. two packages of 90lbs each.
- Use origin weight (few requests): If cart weight is **180lbs** with one child product of **50lb** and other of **130lbs,** UPS will calculate the separate rate for **130lbs** and **50lbs** package by sending two requests to API and sum them up. For eg. of **130lbs** package costs **$100** and **50lbs** package cost **$60** the final shipping cost will be **$100 + $60=$160.**

Comment: I have tried the `Use Origin Weight` option to allow for multiple requests, no item being more than 20lbs, the total weight comes to 405lbs. I would think they'd split it into 20 requests and come back with some kind of calculated rate, however the error message comes as `<ErrorDescription>The maximum per package weight for the selected service from the selected country or territory is 150.00 pounds.</ErrorDescription>`. With this, I've also tried changing packaging from our usual container of `Customer Packaging` to `Pallet` to no avail. Same old issue. Any ideas?

Comment: UPS has a standard on palletizing shipment. How about using `customer supplied package` in your container settings. And also you can try to contact UPS about on how to use their freight services.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, but only found paid modules that required a monthly service fee. Ended up having this module made from an old magento v1 exention that is no longer supported. Try this module. It works with Magento v2 and adds the option to get UPS LTL Freight Shipping.

https://github.com/jerdill/jmodz